# How do I return a promise using .then after setTimeout is done?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm writing an addition function using promises (not async/await) which needs to be performed after 1000ms. I am given a function that creates the promise for me with a setTimeout inside it

```
const delayedPromise = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

So far I have written the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
const delayedPromise = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function validation(num1, num2) {
  if (!Number.isFinite(num1) || !Number.isFinite(num2)) {
    throw new Error('Use only numbers');
  }

function add(num1, num2) {
  validation(num1, num2);
  return num1 + num2;
}

// This is where I could use some guidance
const addPromise = (number1, number2) => {
  delayedPromise(1000)
    .then(result => result === add(number1, number2));
};



//My test
describe.only('promise calculator', () => {
  it('add works fine', done => {
    calculator.addPromise(1, 2).then(result => {
      try {
        assert.equal(3, result);
        done();
      } catch (e) {
        done(e);
      }
    });
  });
```

My understanding is that I am passing two parameters to my function, then call `delayedPromise` to create my promise with a timer of 1000ms, and then using `.then` I am calling the `add` function, passing it the two numbers and assigning that value to `result`.

However my test doesn't pass since I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`. I don't understand why it's not defined, you can get the value of a promise using `.then`, so I'm thinking maybe what's inside the `.then` is not correctly defined.
Can someone with a more experienced eye point me in the right direction please?
Thank you

Comment: It's a typo-level error: Your `addPromise` function doesn't return anything. If you want to use the promise from `delayedPromise(1000).then()`, you have to *return* that from `addPromise`. Literally just add `return` in front of `delayedPromise(1000)` in `addPromise`.

Comment: `setTimeout(resolve, ms)` effectively calls the function as `resolve()` after the delay. `resolve` takes an argument which will be the resolved value; that’s what would be passed as `result` in `.then(result => result === add(number1, number2))`. Since you’re not passing anything, `result` will be `undefined`. You can pass some value using `setTimeout(resolve, ms, someValue)` instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my linter doesn't allow me to add return statement, I get `Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>`.`. And if I do what the linter says then my code becomes `const addPromise = (number1, number2) => delayedPromise(1000) .then(result => result === add(number1, number2));` but it still doesn't pass my test :/

Comment: @FirefliesLftl And this test doesn’t make sense. The resolved value of `addPromise` is a boolean (from `result === add(number1, number2)`). In `assert.equal(3, result);` you’re asserting that this boolean will be equal to `3`. Or is `calculator.addPromise` a different function?

Comment: @SebastianSimon `calculator.addPromise` is how you access the exported as an object `addPromise` from the `test.js` file. The test should be fine and I can't change it. Which means my code is not right. When `addPromise` is called it should calculate the sum of the two numbers with a delay of 1000 ms using promises, but i can't use async/await.

Comment: @FirefliesLftl If the test cannot be changed, then `addPromise` needs to be changed. An `addPromise` that would pass the test looks like this: `const addPromise = (a, b) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, add(a, b)));`.

Comment: @FirefliesLftl - I think you must have misunderstood my comment. It should be: `const addPromise = (number1, number2) => { return delayedPromise(1000).then(result => result === add(number1, number2)); };` (or if your linter wants it to use an expression body: `const addPromise = (number1, number2) => delayedPromise(1000).then(result => result === add(number1, number2));`). The point either way is to **return** the promise created by `then`.